# How to make login page to appear clear when unauthorized error come in angular2

Tags: angular

[image]

In my application i have implemented session expiration time. So when i get session expire message it redirects to login page. But sometimes the login page appears blur. I am not getting why this is happening.
Can anyone give me suggestions how this is happening.

TS:

```
if (res.status == 401) {
      this.toastService.activate("Unauthorized! Please login again");
      setTimeout(() => {
        Cookie.delete("token");
        Cookie.delete("userType");
        Cookie.delete("userID");
        localStorage.clear();
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }, 2500);
```

Comment: what do you mean by blur?

Comment: Thanks for response, it appears like this

Comment: it could be due to the spinner/ovrelay page that you would have implemented at the global level

Comment: it works fine most of time but sometimes it appears like this, can you pls guide me how can i solve this

Comment: we can not help further without taking a look at complete code. Can you create a minimum reproducible example on stackblitz?

Comment: as @DeepakJha mentioned, check your `overlay` code

Comment: hi, as per my observation, i get that type of issue when i open modal popup, the screen appears to be blur, so at that time if error occurs and redirects to login page the modal css remains same so is that issue